# Are there a cloud service that was reliably schedule execute a job at exact time?

Tags: web-services, cloud, job-scheduling, serverless-framework

I was writing server with serverless model, currently aws lambda. And have a requirement to run a job on exact datetime

Currently now I was running a cron job with aws cloudwatch to execute my server every minute, find all tasks which has timestamp older than present then do those task. Which is both wasteful and sometimes make a delay or in advanced by one minute from the actual time it need (because cloudwatch has maximum frequency only one ping per one minute). Not a desirable approach

And the work is not the same everyday. It can be dynamic datetime by client to ping my server

I wish there should be some service that like a message queue but can actively call target URL on scheduling timestamp. Is there something like that? It could be any service outside aws if it can put a URL for request

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other solutions seem promising but there are another solution I found

using step functions wait state

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-wait-state.html

<s>I cannot use it in my region yet because my region is singapore and it cannot be used across region. Currently now I would try to see a dynamodb solution above</s>

As of 2018 step function was generaly available and work as expected

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered getting small EC2 instance and then set up cron jobs there? It can then publish events to SNS or directly call required tasks. And you should be able to schedule new jobs dynamically as well.

Comment: Hi @TofigHasanov. If its a schedule job, isn't it more cost effective and convenient to use a Lambda Scheduled Event to execute the Cron job than using a EC2?

Comment: By the way thanks for pointing out the TTL issue. I have removed the answer involved TTL.

Comment: Well,yes, that was the last option I would do. because I am mere programmer so I don't want to maintain a live server by myself. I wish things like this could have done by some service that would be more reliable than writing ec2 from scratch. Thanks for your advice though

Answer (score 2):

You can use DynamoDB with [TTL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.html), DynamoDB Streams and AWS Lambda for this.

Since the schedule is dynamic and coming from the user, you can save those items in a DynamoDB table with its TTL set to the scheduled execution time.

When the TTL is reached for an item, it will create a DynamoDB Stream which you can then use to trigger a Lambda function.

References:

- [DynamoDB Streams and Time To Live](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/time-to-live-ttl-streams.html)
- [DynamoDB Streams and AWS Lambda Triggers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html)

Comment: I like this idea. Dynamodb streams are checked 4x per second so that seems like an acceptable delay compared to polling.

Comment: @TrentBartlem Where did you get that info?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-ddb.html - 

"Stream-based model – This is a model (see Event Source Mapping), where AWS Lambda polls the stream 4 times per second and, when it detects new records, invokes your Lambda by passing the update event as parameter."

Comment: This seem promising. I would try experiment with it

Comment: Keep in mind that AWS does not guarantee the exact time of expiration on a TTL. An item may be deleted [up to 48 hours after its TTL expires](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/howitworks-ttl.html).

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, why not have the lambda wake on a Cloudwatch alert, then check for tasks every 5 seconds until 55 seconds have elapsed?

Comment: Second from last option because I don't want to waste computation time of lambda. It would cost me more than EC2

Comment: Then dial down the RAM of that instance to the lowest you can. If necessary, you can offload actually processing the tasks to another lambda using SNS.

Comment: @Thaina Lambda's actually cheaper in your cheap case. Probably free.

Answer (score 1):

You likely already found a solution to this but my service https://posthook.io may be good fit for your use case. It lets you schedule 'hooks' with an API call like this:

```
curl https://api.posthook.io/v1/hooks \
-H 'X-API-Key: ${POSTHOOK_API_KEY}' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{
    "path": "/webhooks/ph/event_reminder",
    "postAt": "2018-07-03T01:11:55Z",
    "data": {
        "eventID": 25
    }
}'
```

Then from your lamdba function you can either use the data you passed in as `data` or the `hook`'s unique ID to look something up in your database and do the needed work. A free account allows you to schedule 500 of these requests a month.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2018 there was Azure Logic Apps. An equivalence service to aws step function on azure. It contains delay connector that can schedule delay time

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-delay

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use EventBridge scheduler - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/scheduler/latest/UserGuide/schedule-types.html#one-time